# How to change color on JFoenix's progress bar

Tags: java, css, javafx, jfoenix

I am trying to change the color of the progress-bar found on the JFoenix's library (http://www.jfoenix.com). I'm using Java and JavaFX, here is my sample css:

```
.progress-bar {
-fx-accent: #4059a9;}
```

It should work, but instead it disables the color.

With css enabled:

[image]

With css disabled (default color showing):

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that your problem is caused by the background insets.

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.jfx-progress-bar > .track, .jfx-progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

Now the styling works:

```
.jfx-progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

The background color may be messed up after doing this, you can fix it with this:

```
.jfx-progress-bar > .track {
    -fx-background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```